# SSIS Truncation in Flat file source

Tags: ssis-2012

I am new to SSIS, I am importing a flat file data into SQL Server.  It throws error while importing data in the flat file source task.

```
[Flat File Source [60]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "DCN_NAME" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

[Flat File Source [60]] Error: The "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[DCN_NAME]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[DCN_NAME]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

[image]

How to solve this issue. I don't have problem in destination.Is it possible to change the source field length?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the source length in source connection manager. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information to answer your question. Here is what I can gleam from what you have provided.

Your SSIS package is read a flat file and it assumes DCN_Name is data DT_STR
(type char). Confirm the origin and the destination have the same data type. If they do not, use a [Data Conversion] function which is found on the left side on the screen under Data Flow.

Be mindful that while SQL uses varchar and nvarchar, SSIS uses DT_WSTR and DT_STR. It can get confusing. In the link below you will find a SSIS to SQL Data Type Conversion

[enter link description here](https://sqlservercentral.com/blogs/ssis-to-sql-server-data-type-translations)

Answer (score 0):

The errors generated by SSIS are counter intuitive.

The solution was use a data conversion because the source and destination were different data types.